# How do I select :before and :after of an element (not its content)?

Tags: html, css

Normally, `:before` and `:after` would do this

```
.foo:before {

}

.foo:after {

}
```

Result:

```
<div class="foo">
:before
<div class="somecontent"></div>
:after
</div>
```

Is it possible to select the following `:before` and `:after` for `.foo`?

```
:before
<div class="foo">
</div>
:after
<div class="bar">
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Answer (score 1):

:before and :after doesn't **select** elements, it creates new ones and inserts them before or after so no this is not possible.

You also cannot traverse upwards in the hierarki with css as the selector is never aware of its parent element.

Answer (score 1):

No such pseudo-elements exist. In fact, there are no pseudo-elements in CSS that exist outside of the originating element in terms of the formatting structure. All existing pseudo-elements (defined in Selectors 3, Pseudo-Elements 4 and elsewhere) appear as descendants of the originating element.

That's not to say that you *couldn't* propose new pseudo-elements that exist outside of their originating element, though — the old version of css-content had things like `::outside` and `::alternate`, but those were never implemented in the 12 or so years since they were last drafted due to lack of interest and do not appear in [the css-content rewrite](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-content).